# broken imgs in theme wordpress 5.7

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Actually, i have a personaliced theme in wordpress 5.7, that in localhost it´s ok. But i´m using plugin "backup migration" to upload all my changes in locahost to my hosting... But now, i´m restoring one backup and all my imgs it´s broken...

in my them i have this:

```
<img src=<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()."/images/basic/flag1.png" ?>
```

for example, but in my web browser console (but in hosting) i have this....

```
<img src="http://www.suenosyglamour.com" wp-content="" themes="" suenosyglamour="" images="" basic="" flag1.png="" id="logo" alt="">
```

i don´t understand what it´s the problem now for returned this url when after it´s all ok.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the plugin is not exporting your current theme. Try using this other plugin https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/